# BluePrism passing data between business objects

Tags: object, global, blueprism

I have two BluePrism Business Objects spied. I need to open up application 1, read a piece of data from it, and then inform application 2/ the second business object of the value that was read from the other application.

I know I can expose the data item I'm storing the value in to other pages in the business object, but can't figure out how to expose it to different business objects.

I see Start and End stages have input and output parameters but that doesn't seem to work between business objects like I want. I know that Environment variables can be read globally like I want, but I'm not sure if I can programmatically write values to them and if that would be the right approach.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished it BluePrism? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that Environment variables are immutable inside Blue Prism code. They are not designed to be used to pass data directly between two objects. They're instead meant to function as static constants that should only be required to be modified when moving between various environments.

The way you'd accomplish your task in Blue Prism would be something along the lines of the following:

- Read the necessary data in an action, and have the data item to which the data was read be set as an output of the action (configured in your action's End stage properties).
- Configure the Start stage of your second application's action to accept and utilize the input of the data read from the first object.
- Create a Process that ties these objects together with action stages and local data items.

The concept of Processes vs. Objects and inputs/outputs are covered extensively in official Blue Prism documentation (available within the Blue Prism portal, under the "Documents" tab):

- Blue Prism Foundation Training
- Blue Prism Object Design Guide
- Blue Prism Process Creation Guide
- Blue Prism Best Practice Build Overview